# Pushing JSON files to elasticsearch using Python Script: Works but does not show up in Kibana

Tags: python, json, file, elasticsearch, kibana

**Background Information:**

Hi,

I've been trying to push JSON files into Elasticsearch using a custom script, the script runs and finishes - however, when I check Elasticsearch and Kibana the index exists but none of the docs that I'm sending are uploaded. I've done this a countless number of times. Not sure where I am going wrong since this has worked before -

**Code**

```
#Change the IP as desiered 
es = Elasticsearch(
     ['localhost'],
     timeout=420000,
     port=9200
 )

print ("Start")

#Append to this list if all files from a folder have been uploaded 
done_list = []
filenames = os.listdir("/home/directory/file_json")
print(filenames)

for current_folder in filenames:
    for f in glob.glob("/home/directory/file_json/"+current_folder+"/*.json"):
        print("File Open")
        MyFile = open(f).read()
        print("Bulking - "+f)
        es.bulk(MyFile,"test","_doc")
        print("done elasticsearch")
  done_list.append(current_folder)
  print(current_folder + " done")

print ("Finished")
```

If anyone could let me know if this has some sort of error or maybe something I'm missing that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't use this api but elasticsearch probably returns a status message. Grab and inspect the return value of `es.bulk`, or run the script in a debugger and single-step into `es.bulk` (and the functions it calls) to inspect every value returned by an api call.

Comment: First of all, each line of your file should be a json. You have to iterate the file after opening and add all the lines into a list. Push that list instead of file in the bulk API.

`es.bulk(listOfJsonLines, "indexname", "mapping")`

Comment: I'm pretty new to working with Python, so I'm a bit unsure how to do this? I've seen a couple solutions but I haven't been able to apply it to my problem, also thank you for the suggestions!!